# Weak convergence of Dirac measures converges to a Dirac measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a metrizable space and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$. Suppose the sequence of Dirac measures $\delta_{x_n} \xrightarrow{w} P$ where $P$ is some probability measure. Prove that $P = \delta_x$ for some $x \in X$.

I am not sure how to go about proving this exactly...

The definition of weak convergence I am using is the standard one: so $\delta_{x_n} \xrightarrow{w} P$ happens when for every continuous and bounded $f: X \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ we have $\int f  d\delta_{x_n} \xrightarrow{} \int f dP$.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this exercise in Billingsley's book (Convergence of Probability Measures). Here is my solution.

First, if $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence, which we identify by $x_{n_k}\to x$, then it is easy to see that $x_{n_k}\to x \Rightarrow [\delta_{x_{n_k}}\Rightarrow \delta_x]$. Since, $\delta_{x_{n_k}}\Rightarrow P$, we must have $P=\delta_x$.

Now, suppose that $x_n$ does not have any convergent subsequence. Then, it does not have a limit. In particular, none of $x_k$'s can be its limit, hence, for every given $x_k$, there is an $\epsilon_k>0$, such that for a subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ the metric ball $B(x_k,\epsilon_k)$ does not contain any of $x_{n_i}$'s (since $d(x_k,x_{n_i})\geq\epsilon_k,\forall i$).

Since the ball $B(x_k,\epsilon_k)$ is open, we have, by Portmanteau's theorem that,
$$
0=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\delta_{x_n}(B(x_k,\epsilon_k))\geq P(B(x_k,\epsilon_k)).
$$
Next, let $\displaystyle F=\bigcup_n \{x_n\}$. Observe that $F$ does not have a limit point (otherwise, we would be able to identify a subsequence converging to this limit point, contradicting with the hypothesis that $x_n$ does not have any convergent subsequence), hence $F$ must be closed. Therefore, one more application of Portmanteau's theorem gives us,
$$
1=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\delta_{x_n}(F)\leq P(F)\implies P(F)=1.
$$
Finally, since $\displaystyle F\subset \bigcup_n B(x_n,\epsilon_n)$, and since,
$$
1=P(F)\leq P\left(\bigcup_n B(x_n,\epsilon_n)\right)\leq \sum_{n}P(B(x_n,\epsilon_n))=0,
$$
we get a contradiction.

Comment: Is this result true that if $\{ x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{ \infty }$ be a sequence such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N} : x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. , then the sequence $\{ \delta_{X_n} \}$ converges weakly to $\delta_x$, if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =x$?

Answer (score 2):

We can follow (and detail) the following steps.

1. Fix an integer $r$ and construct a continuous and bounded function $f$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x$ belongs to the closure of $F_r:=\bigcap_{n\geqslant r}\{x_n\}$.
2. The definition of weak convergence implies that for each $r$, $\mathbb P(\overline{F_r})=1$.
3. In particular, $\bigcap_r\overline{F_r}$ is non empty. It remains to prove that this set cannot contain two distinct elements